# Dynamic Menu with Angular and Wijmo

Tags: angularjs, menu, angularjs-ng-repeat, wijmo

I am trying to find a way to dynamically create a menu using the Wijmo directive with angular.

To display sub menu i need nested ng-repeat. My nested nj-repeat is working correctly and generating the correct markup but the wijmo menu is only displaying the first level.

```
    <wij-menu>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menuData"> <a>{{item.menu.id}}</a>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="i in item.menu.popup.menuitem"> <a>{{i.value}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </wij-menu>
```

The jsfiddle for it is http://jsfiddle.net/SPNNNJ/y9x7R/5/

In the sample the hard coded menu shows sub menus but the dynamic one does not.

It might have something to do with the way angular evaluates the directive and ng-repeat but i cant seem to find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is some issue on using nested binding of ng-repeat directive with WijMenu. 
Thereby, I have escalated it to the development team for review.

Comment: This issue is fixed in the latest version 34 which is available at this link: http://wijmo.com/downloads/